# ViewBuilder not building, functionality not working

Tags: swiftui, viewbuilder

[image: Simple ViewBuilder not working]

Getting an error: Cannot convert value of type '_ConditionalContent<Text, Text>' to specified type ().

This seems like an error with the latest update.. however I have other ViewBuilders in my code that I am afraid to touch now. I honestly can't see how to make a ViewBuilder simpler than this and it won't build.

**Update: Thanks for the answer, needed to add a return type, not a bug

```
 @ViewBuilder func positiveOrNot(x: Int) {
    if x > 0 {
    Text("Positive")
    } else {
        Text("Negative")
    }
}
```

Comment: the function should return  `some View`

Comment: Also share code as Text format and not an image.